# Knowing that $\pi \in \mathbb R$ is a transcendent element over $\mathbb Q$....

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

> Knowing that $\pi \in \mathbb{R}$ is a transcendent element over $\mathbb{Q}$. Find a subfield $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}$, with $\deg(\pi, \mathbb{F}) = 3$.

I know the answer is $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^3)$ but I don't know if the path I took to get to the answer is correct.

If $f$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}$ then $f(\alpha) = 0$ and
$$
x = \pi 
\implies x^3 = \pi^3 
\implies x^3 - \pi^3 = 0 
\implies \pi^3 = \alpha = x.
$$

That's what I could think of, but I don't know if the argument is valid?

Grateful for the attention.

Comment: The element $\alpha = \pi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}$ (not the polynomial $f$). The property of being algebraic means that its a root of the polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, but your argument isn't so clear.

Let $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}(\pi^3)$, and define the polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ by $f(x) = x^3 - \pi^3$. Clearly, $\pi$ is a root of $f$. It's less clear (but still true!) that $\pi$ is not a root of a polynomial of lower degree over $\mathbb{F}$, so $\deg_{\mathbb{F}}(\pi) = 3$.